# How to write an empty block

Tags: bcpl

How do you write an empty block? For example, in C, you can have `{ }`. But in BCPL, the equivalent `$( $)` is a syntax error because a block needs at least one statement. So how can you make the following compile?

```
let foo() be $(
    test bar then $(
        //to do
    $) else $(
        writes("baz*n")
    $)
$)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, you could just switch to `unless` to achieve the desired result:

```
// TODO: refactor to use "test", and code other case.
unless bar do $(
    writes("baz*n")
$)
```

If you *really* want to leave it as is, any null-type statement (one having no functional effect) will do. An example of that could be something like:

```
test bar then $(
    // TODO: replace with real code later.
    bar := bar
$) else $(
    writes("baz*n")
$)
```